# LEO or GEO or Lx for a space shipyard?

Tags: future-missions

Given space mining and in situ production goes well, where would a space shipyard best located, LEO, GEO or one of L points and why?

Rough ideas regarding ["specs"](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/120549/realistic-date-and-dimensions-for-a-first-future-space-shipyard) of the shipyard:

- a space shipyard is a place in space to build interplanetary space ships close to today's technology
- for example for colonizing Mars, possibly thousands of units or way more will be required to build and fuel
- space mining assumption is, you would transport iron-nickel asteroids to the shipyard

Logistically, it seems meaningful to me that the location of such a factory should be somewhere close to Earth but I can't argument where exactly, and why.

Comment: I don't think this extremely terse question can be answered in any meaningful way.  If you care to expand and explain what you mean by a space shipyard, what it will build, your assumptions about space mining and where it takes place, you might have something. Otherwise, no.

Comment: @peterh thanks; the question does not suggest a vote but an argument why e.g. LEO would be most suitable over other options. If of course possible, here I'm not sure.

Comment: @J.Doe I think Lagrange-points might be useful is fuel is an issue (most likely it will be), but time is not. Thus, chaotical, very cost-effective trajectories can be used for robotic spaceships to collect the mined substances. Btw, I think it is very unlikely that iron-nickel would be ever so costly that it would be reasonable to mine it in other planets. I am thinking on more interesting things (gold, platinum, He3 will be the first).